# Bluetooth file transfer Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, file-transfer

I am facing a problem in sending large files over bluetooth sockets. Smaller files get transferred correctly. I believe upto 161280 bytes get transferred correctly.

**EDIT:** I did some more testing and narrowed down the cause. It seems that

```
outStream.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
```

in the sending code part is NOT writing more than 161280 bytes. I saw this behavior by not closing the socket connection, thereby causing the `read` in the receiving part to "block" on 161280 bytes. What is wrong with the bluetooth output stream here? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 2:**
Doing this lets it through.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < mybytearray.length ; i++){
    outStream.write(mybytearray[i]);
}
```

**Sending code:**

```
    try {
        outStream = mBluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
        Log.d(TAG,"outStream created success!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG,
                "ON RESUME: Output stream creation failed.",
                e);
    }

    File myFile = new File(file_name);
    Log.d(TAG,"file /source.pdf created success!");

    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int)myFile.length()];
    Log.d(TAG,"file length() =" + (int)myFile.length());

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    Log.d(TAG,"fis created");

    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis,1272254 );
    Log.d(TAG,"bis created success");

    bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
    Log.d(TAG,"ALL Bytes read from bis");

    outStream.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    Log.d(TAG,"BYTES WRITTEN to OUTSTREAM of socket");


    outStream.flush();
    Log.d(TAG,"bytes flushed");
    outStream.close();
```

**Receiving code:**

```
// Attach the i/p stream to the socket
    try {
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        mIn = in;
        Log.d(TAG, "input stream acquired");

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Create output streams & write to file
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/copy.pdf");
    try {
        bytesRead = mIn.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        Log.d(TAG, "bytesRead first time =" + bytesRead);
        current = bytesRead;

        do {
            Log.d(TAG, "do-while -- current: " + current);
            bytesRead = mIn.read(buffer, current,
                    buffer.length - current);
            Log.d(TAG, "bytesRead: =" + bytesRead);

            if (bytesRead >= 0)
                current += bytesRead;
        } while (bytesRead > -1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "do while end:-- buffer len= "
                + buffer.length + "  current: " + current);

        fos.write(buffer);
        Log.d(TAG, "fos.write success! buffer: "
                + buffer.length + "  current: " + current);

        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
}
socket.close();
```

**Logcat:**

```
D/ReceiveService( 5761): do-while -- current: 155232
D/ReceiveService( 5761): bytesRead: =1008
D/ReceiveService( 5761): do-while -- current: 156240
D/ReceiveService( 5761): bytesRead: =1008
D/ReceiveService( 5761): do-while -- current: 157248
D/ReceiveService( 5761): bytesRead: =1008
D/ReceiveService( 5761): do-while -- current: 158256
D/ReceiveService( 5761): bytesRead: =1008
D/ReceiveService( 5761): do-while -- current: 159264
D/ReceiveService( 5761): bytesRead: =1008
D/ReceiveService( 5761): do-while -- current: 160272
D/ReceiveService( 5761): bytesRead: =1008
D/ReceiveService( 5761): do-while -- current: 161280
W/System.err( 5761): java.io.IOException: Software caused connection abort
W/System.err( 5761):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 5761):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.read(BluetoothSocket.java:307)
W/System.err( 5761):    at   android.bluetooth.BluetoothInputStream.read(BluetoothInputStream.java:96)
W/System.err( 5761):    at com.bt.server.ReceiveService$AcceptThread.run(ReceiveService.java:141)
```

I am using Motorola Milestone. Android 2.1

Comment: Paste the logs of the sending device including timestamps. Hope sending & receiving is being done on a separate thread.

Comment: Seach SO for "Software caused connection abort".

Comment: Yes they are on separate threads. Different phones. The sending device sends data almost instantaneously.

Comment: Hey can you post the full source code I am also stuck on this sending file problem using Bluetooth. If you share your code then I can get solution of my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi,I tried this code.But i have some doubts.1) Is any protocol  is used for transfering data from one phone to another here.If so which the protocol used?

Comment: Well I am using simple bt sockets here. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord%28java.util.UUID%29

Comment: This is just part of the code and I believe it won't work as is. Go through the Bluetooth chat program http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html. Its an excellent reference. I derived my code from it too.

Comment: @Shjiraz.... Can u post your full code?

Comment: @shiraz what is "mIn" in your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by sending small chunks of data out to the bluetooth outstream. It turned out that 8 * 1024 was a good buffer size, which helped in sending out data seamlessly over the stream as well as preventing corruption of data at the receiving end.

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis, 8 * 1024);


byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int len
while ((len = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    outStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
```

Comment: I am having a problem with send simple image file over bluetooth using bluetooth chat sample. Actually, My requirement was an send any file oevr bluetooth. For this how can I set the buffer size, how to receive small chunk of data and combine it at the receiver side. Could u please share me your code.

Comment: can you have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954082/send-text-file-using-bluetooth-sockets-in-android

Comment: I'm developing a solution which is based on your approach, but I'm stuck on outStream.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);, it simply won't write data to output stream. No errors, file is created with size of 0 bytes and logs stop right after bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length). Any ideas?

Comment: @shiraz Dear shiraz I am struggling to transfer any file greater than 1024 bytes. Can you please share your send/receive code here to help us who are struggling? Thank you