# Sending full file over bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm developing Android application to send file between two devices. I'm able to do the discovery, connect and send an object over Bluetooth and receive it properly. So my communication infrastructure is working as required. My only problem is that when I want to send a large object or a file, it turned out that I'm limited to the 1024 bytes size as per the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748219/bluetooth-file-transfer-android). This actually makes the process of sending a file slow. Is there a way to send a file in full and make use of Bluetooth speed? the loop seems to make the process of sending the file very slow.